# What is the VBA coding for getting data from multiple tables in Access?

Tags: vba, microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2010

I am a newbie in access VBA coding. I would like to get the data from multiple tables which table name begin with "AB" and show the result in the combo box. I have around 50++ tables and there will be more tables imported in the future.

I had tried the following coding for getting data from one table,

```
strRowsource = "SELECT ID FROM AD12"
Combo10.RowSource = strRowsource
```

Is there any alternative ways to get the data from multiple tables instead of key in multiple times of the coding above. Appreciate for the help!

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-access-programming-92eb616b-3204-4121-9277-70649e33be4f